# Qt generate Keypress(keyboard) to the system(OS) a cross-platfom way

Tags: c++, qt, operating-system, cross-platform, keystroke

Is there a way to generate keystrokes using Qt, so that it will work on windows, linux, and mac. I know Qt has A QEvent class for that, but it applies the keypress event only to its own window, not to the OS. I could do it using the winAPI, but that will be for windows only, i want a cross-platform code source if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No such functionality exists within Qt. You will have to use platform-specific APIs.

Comment: Really ?! they could have done it think, like implementing platform-specific solutions and selecting which one to use depending on the current OS, while letting us write a single piece of code that will interact with the platform-specific.... Anyway, i guess i'll do it myself

Comment: @Xsmael An infinite number of things are within the realm of possibility. A dedicated person is all that's needed to bring them to fruition. Get a Qt account, sign the [contributor agreement](http://www.qt.io/contributionagreement/), and push your change! :) IOW: Nobody bothered implementing it. I know I never needed such functionality. Usually communicating with other applications by pretending to be a keyboard ends up an ugly hack. But I have no doubt that, properly done, such a feature would be welcome.

Comment: okay, i'll consider it, but why is that ugly ? it can have many descent applications, even useful ones.

Comment: @Xsmael It's ugly because ultimately you're using it as a means of communicating with another application by pretending to be a human user. Outside of testing, or writing userland keyboard drivers, it's generally a hack. If an application is meant to be communicated with from other software, it'll offer a relevant API. Otherwise, you'll be fighting with windmills, more or less.

Comment: oh, now i get you, you're totally right, as if i wanted to interact with the OS , I will rather send commands, but if I want to allow a "human" to use his computer remotely(let's say a presentation remote), the program will need to "pretend" to be him on the actual computer, but still the source is human. Thanks for your point ;)